# Regarding page feeds versus post feeds and RSS Updates in Jekyll

Tags: rss, jekyll

For each category in my Jekyll site, I have a static page with a record of all changes that have happened regarding that category.

For instance, a network change log, a lighting change log, a building and facilities change log, etc.

I *could* simply create a new post in the appropriate category and write about the change, but that's more of a detailed account.

I would rather keep a running journal in a page format.  So here's the question:

If I create an XML feed that finds only a single page, ie:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.title == 'Network Change Log' %}
        do this xml feed stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I'll get a single entry in my feed for that page, and the only thing that will change will be the first part of the body of the content and the `site.time`.

If the feed is formatted correctly, will the automatic e-mail engines like Mailchimp consider each revision or each change to the page as a "new post" like a post feed would, thereby triggering an e-mail update as though there was a new post?

The goal is to monitor the feed and trigger automated updates for that single page any time it is updated.

Thanks in advance!